# Component with optional value prop

Tags: vue.js

I'm writing a re-usable component. It's basically a section with a header and body, where if you click the header, the body will expand/collapse.

I want to allow the consumer of the component to use `v-model` to bind a boolean to it so that it can expand/collapse under any condition it wants, but within my component, the user can click to expand/collapse.

I've got it working, but it *requires* the user of the component to use v-model, if they don't, then the component doesn't work.

I essentially want the consumer to decide if they care about being able to see/change the state of the component or not. If they don't, they shouldn't have to supply a `v-model` attribute to the component.

Here's a simplified version of my component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div @click="$emit('input', !value)">            
            <div>
                <slot name="header">Header</slot>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div :class="{ collapse: !value }">        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div>
                        <slot></slot>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Vue, Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";   


    @Component
    export default class CollapsibleSection extends Vue {
        @Prop({ default: true }) public value: boolean;
    }
</script>
```

## Update:

I've come up with a solution that meets my requirements functionally. It's a little more verbose than I would like, so if anyone has a more terse solution, I would love to read about it, and I will gladly mark it as the accepted answer if it meets my requirements with less code/markup.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div @click="toggle">            
            <div>
                <slot name="header">Header</slot>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div :class="{ collapse: !currentValue }">        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div>
                        <slot></slot>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Vue, Component, Prop, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";   


    @Component
    export default class CollapsibleSection extends Vue {
        @Prop({ default: true }) public value: boolean;

        public currentValue = true;

        public toggle() {
            this.currentValue = !this.currentValue;
            this.$emit('input', this.currentValue);
        }

        public mounted() {
            this.currentValue = this.value;
        }

        @Watch('value')
        public valueChanged() {
            this.currentValue = this.value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, can you clarify what you really want to do? It's really hard to follow.

Comment: If my component can be used as `<collapsible-section>...</collapsible-section>`, then I want to allow the consumer to provide a `v-model` so that they can know the current state AND change it; however, I do not want to _require_ that they provide one (if they don't, they have no way of knowing or changing the state, but that's OK since they didn't provide a `v-model`). I just came up with a solution that I will post, but it's a bit verbose, so I'd be happy to learn about a more terse way to provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update works and has the right gist in general, but instead of a watcher it would be better to use a computed property. See [the docs for computed properties and watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) for more info.

I've excluded the class notation in the below snippet to have it runnable on-site.

```js
Vue.component('expandable', {
  props: {
    value: {
      // Just to be explicit, not required
      default: undefined,
      validator(value) {
        return typeof value === 'boolean' || typeof value === 'undefined';
      },
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div class="expandable">
      <p @click="toggle()">toggle</p>
      <slot v-if="isOpen" />
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      internalValue: true,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isOpen() {
      return (typeof this.value !== 'undefined') ? this.value : this.internalValue;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.internalValue = !this.internalValue;
      this.$emit('input', !this.isOpen);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.expandable {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <expandable>
    <p>no model</p>
  </expandable>
  <expandable v-model="isOpen">
    <p>has model</p>
  </expandable>
</div>
```

Comment: Ultimately I was hoping to not have an "internalValue", but the more I think about it, I don't think that's possible. Your solution solves the problem with a little less code, so that makes me happy. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianBall Yes, without some kind of an internal variable you will have nothing to bind updates to — the default prop value is an immutable value that you can't write to.